# coroutine executes only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game where a car moves on a road, which has triggers along it. The purpose is to detect when the car enters those triggers and to do stuff depending on the trigger.

For the one I am having trouble, the camera is supposed to slowly move towards a second position which is behind and slightly above the car.

Here is what I tried:

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{


    if (other.attachedRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > 20.0f)
    {
        StartCoroutine(tst());
    }

}
IEnumerator tst()
{
    Camera cam = Camera.main;
    Vector3 newPosition = cam.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).position;
    cam.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cam.transform.position, newPosition, camUnit);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

}
```

The camUnit is equal 1f but the problem is that it doesn't move to the correct location, as in if I just assign it the new position the camera is in a different perspective than the code above and it is instant and not slow to move to the next position.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly after your `yield` you are exiting the Coroutine. With what you describe, you actually want this in some form of loop, and `yield` after doing what you need to do. Then, after the function resumes you decide whether you go again and yield again, or continue on towards the exit of the Coroutine.

```
    bool isDone = false;
    while(!isDone)
    {
        Camera cam = Camera.main;
        Vector3 newPosition = cam.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).position;
        cam.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cam.transform.position, newPosition, camUnit);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        isDone = EnsureCameraLocation(); // Do whatever check you need to do to figure out if the camera is where you want it yet
    }
```

Note that the `yield` is **inside** the `while` statement which is what will make the Coroutine seamless.

Comment: doesn't this mean that the loop will always wait 3 seconds before starting over again ?

Comment: that's what you wrote, so yes. If you want it to be smooth, you need to accommodate that. For example, use `yield return null` so it happens next frame, and instead of using `camUnit` calculate a value based upon something like `deltaTime`

Comment: I see.. thank you, your answer was a great help, I seemed to have misunderstood the use of a coroutine and loops on calls that are not frame based.